# Doesn´t render items React useState

Tags: reactjs

I would like to add new tasks but they are not rendered, here is this part of my code:

```
  setItemsFromBackend([...itemsFromBackend, {id: uuidv4(), content: text }]);


  setText("")
}

const [itemsFromBackend, setItemsFromBackend] = useState([{ id: uuidv4(), content: "First task" }]);

const [text, setText] = useState("");

const columnsFromBackend = {

  [uuidv4()]: {
    name: "Requested",
    items: itemsFromBackend,
  },
  [uuidv4()]: {
    name: "To do",
    items: [],
  },
  [uuidv4()]: {
    name: "In Progress",
    items: [],
  },
  [uuidv4()]: {
    name: "Done",
    items: [],
  },
};

<div>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>
</div>
```

Here is the complete project in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/trello-task-yhbmu?file=/src/Kanban.jsx

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, instead of a `div` use a proper `form` around the form elements. And instead of listening on the button's `click` event, listen on form `submit`, so you can add an item by hitting the Enter key too, not just button click.

```
<form onSubmit={addItem}>
  <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
  <button>Add</button>
</form>
```

I think, you should update the way you handle state. At the moment there are different pieces everywhere. You use `columns`, `columnsFromBackend` and these also contain the `itemsFromBackend` state. And with all these it's way too easy to mutate the state without realising it.

In your `addItem` method you update `itemsFromBackend` by using `setItemsFromBackend` and you forgot that you should also update the `columns` by using `setColumns`. If you don't use `setColumns`, React will not be aware of the changes and you won't see the updates because React won't re-render the components.

Not sure what you receive from your backend, but you should either use the `columnsFromBackend` object as state (which doesn't seem to be flat enough), or you could create a new state for each columns. You kind of use both of these at the moment by storing the requested column in `itemsFromBackend`.

The following snippet uses only `columns` and `text` states, everything unnecessary is removed, and `columns` is updated in `addItem` the same way as you do it in `onDragEnd`:

```
function Kanban() {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState({
    [uuidv4()]: {
      name: "Requested",
      items: [{ id: uuidv4(), content: "First task" }]
    },
    [uuidv4()]: {
      name: "To do",
      items: []
    },
    [uuidv4()]: {
      name: "In Progress",
      items: []
    },
    [uuidv4()]: {
      name: "Done",
      items: []
    }
  });
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const addItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const item = { id: uuidv4(), content: text };
    const requestedColumnId = Object.entries(columns).find(
      (i) => i[1].name === "Requested"
    )[0];
    const column = columns[requestedColumnId];

    setColumns({
      ...columns,
      [requestedColumnId]: {
        ...column,
        items: [...column.items, item]
      }
    });
    setText("");
  };

  const onDragEnd = (result, columns, setColumns) => {
    // no changes here
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", height: "100%" }}>
      <form onSubmit={addItem}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      {/* no changes below */}
```

You can find the forked sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/trello-task-forked-okix3

Comment: I really appreciate your help, it is wonderful to receive such a detailed response. I effectively forgot to update the columns, I will study the proposed code well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
setItemsFromBackend({ ...itemsFromBackend, id: uuidv4(), content: text });
```

`itemsFromBackend` is an array, so you're spreading in the wrong spot. Try this:

```
setItemsFromBackend([...itemsFromBackend, {id: uuidv4(), content: text }]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, It is true it looks strange, I just changed it but it does not work.